# Import or Programmatically create nodes with Videos

Tags: 7, nodes, files

I'm working on a new drupal site which I need to migrate from an existing non-drupal site. I need to be able to import the old blog posts as Article nodes (either through some standard import mechanism or I can write some php to programmatically create the nodes).

However, I'm not sure how to handle creating Image and Video data in a node, especially with the need for transcoding video after creation of the node. So, two questions:

1) How can I programmatically create nodes with binary Image and Video data?

2) When I do create a node with Video data, will the post-create transcoding job be started? I'm using Zencoder to do my transcoding.

I am not using the local filesystem for drupal, I'm storing all of my files in Rackspace Cloud Files, however, I can handle it if I need to use the local filesystem temporarily during import and then manually move things over to Cloud Files. This is only a one-time event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the Migrate [module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate). It's got a kinda steep learning curve but plenty of [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/415260) available.

The [Migrate Extras](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_extras) module provides integration with the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module, which could help with the video field specifically.

Comment: You were NOT kidding about a steep learning curve, phew. I haven't gotten to the Video portion yet, but I'm getting the hang of the migrate module and making progress.

Comment: Awesome, once you get the hang of it its actually pretty sweet!  Check out Commerce Kickstart for some nice working examples...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Datasources](http://drupal.org/project/datasources).

> Datasources provides a framework to describe and manage datasource to
>   import in Drupal.

I've written a generic module to import data into Drupal previously!