# How to use Migrate module to import Videos?

Tags: 7, files, migrations

I have a bunch of blog posts from an old site, some of which have .flv videos. I'm using the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module to migrate all of these blog posts and the videos are the only piece left. I'm using the [Video](http://drupal.org/project/video) module for the embedded videos in my blog posts.

How do I use the Migrate module to import those videos into drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to migrate a few thousand flv and mp4 videos. I ended up just migrating the file name into a field, uploading the videos files to s3 and then using a custom node.tpl.php to render the player:

```
<?php
  //display legacy videos
  $mediaid = $content['field_mediaid']['#items'][0]['value'];
  if ($mediaid != '') {
      $video2 = '<a href="http://mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/ka/'.$mediaid.'.mp4" id="player" class="flowplayer"></a>';
              flowplayer_add('#player', array(
                'clip' => array(
                  'autoPlay' => TRUE
                ),
              )); 
        print $video2;
 }
 //hide the mediaid field from display
 hide($content['field_mediaid']);
?>
```

Not very elegant but it got the job done. I used migrate 7.x-2.2 back then, maybe 2.5 has better video and/or file import features.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a Migrate solution. I'd like to avoid non-Migrate answers b/c they might discourage actual answers. Can you move this answer over to my other, more general question? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50616/import-or-programmatically-create-nodes-with-videos

Comment: I can accept it as the answer over there, but I'd rather not accept it as the answer here.